# lsb_release -a gives 10!

Tags: raspbian, update, version-control

I followed [this tutorial](https://baddotrobot.com/blog/2017/10/26/upgrade-raspian-jessie-to-stretch/), trying to upgrade directly from *Jessie* to *Buster* instead of *Jessie* to *Stretch*.

then, when i check the version with

```
$ lsb_release -a
```

I get this!

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10.0 (n/a)
Release:        10.0
Codename:       n/a
```

What's happening? how can I get my Jessie back? or finish the upgrade?

Comment: What is wrong in your opinion? You upgraded to Buster (v10) and got exactly that. Of course you made a backup before upgrading to Buster...

Comment: code name is n/a. isn't it wrong?

Comment: I would suspect it's a result of upgrading instead of a fresh install. It's just a code name so who cares...

Comment: If you choose to ignore the Foundation advice to perform a fresh install expect problems

Comment: For comparison, Armbian reports 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

Which is wrong for entirely other reasons...